Can I solve the problem that occurs when booting the linux on versatilepb board using qemu?
Im studying about the U-boot. I used QEMU emulation to boot Linux on a board called versatilepb.
The latest version of U-Boot no longer supports versatilepb, so I used U-Boot version 2010.03. When using the latest version of Linux, there were compatibility issues with the dtb, preventing it from booting properly, so I used Linux version 4.1.6. Additionally, I used the following commands to create a file called flash.bin, which includes both U-Boot and uImage.
dd if=/dev/zero of=flash.bin bs=1 count=5M 
dd if=u-boot.bin of=flash.bin conv=notrunc bs=1 
mkimage -A arm -C none -O linux -T kernel -d /home/ghjeon/linux-4.1.6/arch/arm/boot/zImage -a 0x10000 -e 0x10000 zImage.uimg
dd if=zImage.uimg of=flash.bin conv=notrunc bs=1 seek=2M

I then executed QEMU with the following command, and it booted successfully when I entered bootm 0x210000.
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -kernel flash.bin -nographic

However, I'm curious about something because when creating flash.bin, uImage was located at 2M, which is 0x200000. Even considering the U-Boot header, a more appropriate start address for zImage would be 0x200040, but I don't understand why the kernel image is considered to be at 0x210000.
Furthermore, even when I analyzed zImage.uimg using binwalk, the actual Linux kernel's zImage has an offset of 0x40.
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0xFA419419, created: 2024-06-27 03:46:40, image size: 2115016 bytes, Data Address: 0x10000, Entry Point: 0x10000, data CRC: 0x63803D2C, OS: Linux, CPU: ARM, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: none, image name: ""
64            0x40            Linux kernel ARM boot executable zImage (little-endian)
17676         0x450C          gzip compressed data, maximum compression, from Unix, last modified: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 (null date)


